# Crop outer parts of frame and rejoin

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video 3000x1000.

I want the left part of video 1001x1000 and the right part of video 999x1000 to create a video 2000x1000. Center of original frame just dropped.

Is this possible with ffmpeg in one pass? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex '[0:v]split[l0][r0];[l0]crop=1001:1000:0:0[l1];[r0]crop=999:1000:2001:0[r1];[l1][r1]hstack[out]' -map '[out]' ouput.mkv
```

Comment: It would be better if you could explain a little bit what this command does. This will help future readers and in particular those who don't have much experience with ffmpeg. .

Comment: As I understand, every filter takes a number of streams and produces a number of streams. E.g. split takes source video stream 0 [0:v] and clones it to streams [l0] and [r0]. Then crop takes [l0] crops it and produces [l1] ... finally hstack takes [l1] and [r1] and place them side-by-side then produce stream [out]. Then -map maps stream [out] to an output stream.